# Is it possible to identify which window/usercontrol owns a FrameworkElement?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, frameworkelement

Is it possible to identify which window/usercontrol owns a `FrameworkElement`?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean like `someElement.Parent` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can "walk up" using the `.Parent`-Property until you find the window or usercontrol. Just check the type of the parent while walking up.

Answer (score 7):

Or you could just use the static helper method [GetWindow(DependencyObject dependencyObject)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow(v=vs.110).aspx) from the Window class. This method returns the Window object that hosts the element.

Answer (score 3):

While Fischermaen's answer works for most cases, it'd break if you have templates in your code. In that case, you'd have to check both, `.Parent` and `.TemplatedParent` when you traverse upward